# AndroidStudio/Kotlin - Unresolved reference: ReadWriteProperty - Kotlin version 1.0.0-beta-1038

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, kotlin

I have a working Android project using Kotlin version 1.0.0-beta-1038 in Android Studio.

I can run it using Kotlin in different parts, it compiles and works in the emulator but when I tried to use ReadWriteProperty it gives this error message:

**Unresolved reference: ReadWriteProperty**

[image: Unresolved reference: ReadWriteProperty]

Class called PreferenceUtils.kt:

[image]

build.grade (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.droidcba.oculto"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-beta-1038'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

build.grade (Module: myProject)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: Did you import it? import kotlin.properties.ReadWriteProperty

Comment: Hi @JeremyLyman, I already tried but it also said "Unresolved Reference" in the import line :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Solved! I have to **upgrade the Kotlin Plugin**
>   from Android Studio. It started to recognise "ReadWriteProperty".